# Qt, QDialog buttons not Respondig

Tags: c++, qt

The dialog opens with two buttons, OK and Cancel. None of the buttons responds to user click. I have to press the X on the top right to cancel the dialog.

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == mTabWidget && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) 
    {
        // query and set tab(s) names
        QTabWidget *tab = qobject_cast<QTabWidget *>(obj);
        if(tab)
        {
            QDialog dlg;
            QVBoxLayout la(&dlg);
            QLineEdit ed;
            la.addWidget(&ed);
            QDialogButtonBox bb(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
            la.addWidget(&bb);
            dlg.setLayout(&la);
            if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
            {
                tab->setTabText(0, ed.text());
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Am I missing any `connect()` line  or signals? I tried to read the Qt documentation, but from what I understood, calling `QDialogButtonBox::OK` gets processed as Accepted.

UPDATE :

New Dialog Function

OK, i have created a new function that takes care of the Dialog box, i am calling it from the event function. it is still not responding, now on the terminal, i see an error that says, : no such slot MainWindow::accept() and another for reject. I know that i have no slots for these two in the .h file. i tried to find how to build the slots but i couldnt, any help would be great. thank you

```
void MainWindow::initializeBOX()
{
 QDialog dlg;
        QVBoxLayout la(&dlg);
        QLineEdit ed;
        la.addWidget(&ed);


        //QDialogButtonBox bb(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
        //btnbox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok | QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);
         QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox::Ok |                QDialogButtonBox::Cancel);

         connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
         connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));

         la.addWidget(buttonBox);
         dlg.setLayout(&la);


        if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
        {
            mTabWidget->setTabText(0, ed.text());
        }

       }
```

Comment: It's a little suspicious that you're `exec`ing a dialog in an event filter. That's likely blocking the processing of further events.

Comment: Any reason you're not using the static [`QString QInputDialog::getText(...)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qinputdialog.html)? It seems to me that you're not doing anything preventing the use.

Comment: @Andrew  i have edited my code can you please check the new function. it is still not responding to the button clicked

Answer (score 0):

Rather than launching the dialog from event filer you should trap [QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseDoubleClickEvent) by overloading that virtual function in your code. And as long as it is a callback already you can do more stuff immediately from there including the dialog. Or maybe send the signal to slot that does the dialog (a bit cleaner). I would do the signal from mouseDoubleClickEvent event handler and make the parent QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent to consume the event to avoid possible complications especially when porting the code to other platform.

Event filters are for non-standard event processing. There is nothing non-standard in your case.

Comment: i have edited my code can you please check the new function. it is still not responding to the button clicked  @AlexanderVX

Comment: AAFF, please see Qt Dialog Examples: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/examples-dialogs.html What you've done is maybe interesting but Qt expects you to write the code in some patter. And please don't use event filter for launching the dialog but event handler.